# Is there any way to possibly block Opera’s VPN option?

Tags: vpn, browser, opera

As a company, We have blocked some websites like Facebook, Twitter in our office. But some employees access them using [Opera VPN](http://www.opera.com/computer/features/free-vpn).

We can't remove Opera browser because we are a web design company and employees need to test web sites using Opera browser too.

So is there way to block the Opera VPN option?

Comment: I didn't try, however there seems to be script, which may help you, as it can find out, which HTTPS proxy IPs are actually available: gist.github.com/spaze/558b7c4cd81afa7c857381254ae7bd10 So then you can block it and update the list regularly.

Comment: On your users' app, you can turn the VPN off and change the Settings file to become Read only so that only an admin can change it.

Answer (score 1):

I was successful in disabling the Opera VPN in OpenWRT using the AdBlock plugin. I added these URLs and now the Opera VPN can't connect to it's network anymore.

```
api.surfeasy.com
de0.opera-proxy.net
api.sec-tunnel.com
sitecheck2.opera.com
opera-mini.net
exchange.opera.com
features.opera-api.com
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made many searches on GeoIP Tools and many forums, and joined all Opera network blocks as I paste below:

```
37.228.108.128/25
107.167.96.0/19
185.26.182.0/23
77.111.244.0/22
82.145.208.0/20
91.203.96.0/22
```

Answer (score 0):

You can block all IP addresses from the Autonomous System (AS) owned by Opera.

```
37.228.104.0/21
82.145.208.0/20
91.203.96.0/22
141.0.8.0/21
185.26.180.0/22
195.189.142.0/23
2001:4c28::/29
```

Source: https://www.ip2location.com/as39832